# Cannot log-in to CP

Tags: control-panel, login

Yes, it's the dreaded unable to log-in issue. Been working fine - latest version EE - for a few weeks (new install) and suddenly today cannot log in. Stays on same page and gives error: **Invalid username or password.**.

Have tried resetting password. Nada. Tried the usual fixes in the config file and also clearing cookies etc. No joy anywhere.

One thing I think *might* be relevant - this is a development site, the real site exists elsewhere under the intended domain. So obviously this one uses a temp domain/IP address and when is completed the idea is to just update the nameservers.

I suspect, but am not sure, that this is somehow coming into play.

Anyone encountered this before?

***Note***: Also in the days prior to this manifesting there was a different issue where after first login attempt nothing would happen, just refresh of page and clearing of fields. But on the second attempt it would allow login. Now it does not allow on any attempt. This has to be related no?

Comment: Try using your email id as username instead. Sometimes setting in Member group changes unknowingly.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work...but it shouldn't do should it? Does EE ever exhibit this behaviour? Didn't think you could use email as login out of the box?

Comment: [doNotCheckMyBlog](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/1140/donotcheckmyblog) is right... I just had this with a fresh install. Use your email address to log in. That's the first time I've seen that behaviour with EE and I've been working with it for 4 years.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you have your EE installation set up to disallow simultaneous log ins. This means that if you are logged into the site from one location/machine then you cannot log in using the same account on a different machine until the other one logs out.

To 'fix' this so you can log in, take a look in the exp_sessions table and remove any sessions that match your member id.

If you are then able to log in, that was the problem.

To turn this off go to Admin->Security and Privacy->Security and Sessions and turn on the option marked "Allow multiple log-ins from a single account?"

Comment: ^^ This is the best place to start, as its a dev site just go nuts, clear your cookies, clear your cache, clear the exp_sessions table and give it another go. Also if you have Firebog get into the console, click the "Persist" button and submit your login, then you can inspect the sent and recieved data including over redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You mention this is a dev site, and I assume from your OP that you have a stage/live server set up too? As you mention your namespace switch-er-oo technique for deployments (btw, Ree-locate is awesome if simulating domains on your local machines is too much).

Is it possible that you logged into the Live/Stage site (ergo gainign the session cookies) then logged into your dev site and because the dev site is configured with the same domain it inherits your live cookies?

Can you still log into/ out of your stage and live enviroments.